# Plugin that does automated validation for inputs in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am using  like below in my react app:

```
<TextField
       required
       id="addtask"
       placeholder="Add your awesome task.."
       className="addtask"
       margin="normal"
/>
```

I would like to know if there is any automated way of validating such inputs on form submit , like in jQuery where you can just pass a few data attributes like so:

```
<input data-validate="notempty" data-error-empty="This feild can't be empty" />
```

Ofcourse i see there is a `error` property for  , which i see the [API](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api), and i can run a function and make error true or false. But wanted to know if there is a automated plugin that does this I.E. Validation just using data attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/) . You can define a `validationSchema` and it will be applied for you ([example](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation)).